# passing a directory into a powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am passing a directory into a powershell script.  I have done this before, but apparently I haven't done it with a directory that has spaces in it: For example...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDks\Windows\v7.0A\bin\
```

Well, simple enough right, just surround it with paren's right?  Wrong...  When it is in my actual script it is throwing the following anoying exception:

```
The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file
, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was include
d, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:275
```

This is being passed into my script as a parameter btw, hence why it is throwing the error at line 1.

Any advice on passing directories as paramters into powershell scripts?

Comment: What are you passing it from? Batch file? C#? ASP? Java?

Comment: just the command line.  I have control over what I send in.

Comment: Can you give us the first line of the script? The issue may not be with the passing of the folder but with the way the script is handling it. Though seeing as it is at character 275, that's a little frightening.

Comment: You need to say exactly how you're calling this PowerShell script. Typing it at the PowerShell command line? From a shell script (batch file)? Task scheduler?

Comment: Sorry, I literally open up a command line and input the string.  Turns out that it was the way I calling the string in my script.  Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting into into quotes, single or double will work.

You can also throw it into a variable first.

Comment: tried single and double quotes and a combination of both.  I still get that exception.